# Built in Decode Function in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, plsql

I am migrating my db from oracle to SQL Server 2008.Can you show a built in function that can work same as oracle's decode? I don't want to write case when in every query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no equivalent function in T-SQL, so you will have to use `CASE`.

See [here](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/oracle_sql_server_differences_equivalents.htm) and [here](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/faq/oracle-functions-p01.aspx).

Comment: @mcb - Yes, you could probably write a UDF that will be doing a `CASE` for you.

Comment: I think it would be impossible to write a UDF the exactly duplicated decode, to replace decode in the general case. Don't SQL Server UDFs require a fixed set of arguments, where DECODE takes a variable number?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from using a CASE statement or write an UDF, I think you are out of luck.

According to [this link](http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/779504-how-decode-sql-server-2005-a), DECODE is becoming somewhat irrelevant in favor off CASE on Oracle to.

> But back to the original topic ...
>   CASE was quickly adopted, and the
>   reason is that it provided new and
>   advantageous functionality over the
>   older decode.
>
> -- Daniel A. Morgan
>   Oracle Ace Director & Instructor University of
>   Washington damorgan@x.washington.edu

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE:

```
Select f1, case f2
                         When 1 then 'A'
                         When 2 then 'B'
                         When 3 then 'C'
                         Else 'Some other'
            End as f2_decode
from MyTable
```

Comment: It is just example :) I fixesd my answer.